# Elegant way to flatten a simd_float4x4 matrix

Tags: arrays, swift, simd

I would like to flatten a `simd_float4x4` or a `simd_float3x3` matrix into a single array of float elements.

For a regular array I would use

```
let arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
print(arr.flatMap { $0 })
```

How can I do this for a `simd_float4x4` or `simd_float3x3` structure elegantly?

I am currently using this,

```
extension simd_float3x3 {
    var array: [Float] {
        return [columns.0.x, columns.0.y, columns.0.z,
                columns.1.x, columns.1.y, columns.1.z,
                columns.2.x, columns.2.y, columns.2.z]
    }
}

let arr = simd_float3x3.init()
print(arr.array.compactMap({$0}))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elegant is in the eye of the beholder.  So far, I've come up with this:

```
let s = simd_float3x3(simd_float3(1, 2, 3), simd_float3(4, 5, 6), simd_float3(7, 8, 9)) 

let y = (0..<3).flatMap { x in (0..<3).map { y in s[x][y] } }

print(y)
```

> ```
> [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
> ```

Comment: Could this be a good opportunity for lazy map?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it looks like vectors `float3` and `float4` already have `map` implementation (via implementing `Sequence`/`Collection` protocol).

So only thing we should do is to implement `Collection` for matrices:

```
extension simd_float3x3: Collection {
    public var startIndex: Int {
        return 0
    }

    public var endIndex: Int {
        return 3 // for `sims_float4x4` it would be 4, number of columns
    }

    public func index(after i: Int) -> Int {
        return i + 1
    }
}
```

and now we can do this:

```
let matrix: simd_float3x3 = initCodeForTheMatrix()
matrix.flatMap { $0 }
```

---

You can declare this handy sub-protocol, to avoid typing same `startIndex` and `index(after:)` for all matrix types:

```
public protocol SIMDCollection: Collection {}
extension SIMDCollection {
    public var startIndex: Int {
        return 0
    }

    public func index(after i: Int) -> Int {
        return i + 1
    }
}

// And use it like this:
extension simd_float3x3: SIMDCollection {
    public var endIndex: Int {
        return 3
    }
}

extension simd_float4x4: SIMDCollection {
    public var endIndex: Int {
        return 4
    }
}

extension simd_float3x2: SIMDCollection {
    public var endIndex: Int {
        return 3
    }
}

// etc
```

It can go even further, because `endIndex` would be the same for all `simd_floatX_Y` with same `X` and any `Y`. It doesn't even matter if it's `*float*` or `*double*` or whatever.